# refit enable passing very long string parameter in get request query

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using .net core 5 and I am using **Refit** third-party library to implement HTTP client with an API. I am facing an issue now when I pass very long string in http get query, i am getting Bad Request because of **Refit cause API exception**. My question is that is there anyway to add configuration to RefitClient which will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to understand why this exception occurs.

Refit third-party libraries should also follow RFC rules. So the only way is to use Post request. There will be no configuration to allow very long strings for http requests.

**Related Post:**

[What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/7687666)